# What is the maximum length of data I can put in a BLOB column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, blob

What is the maximum length of data I can put in a BLOB column in MySQL?

Comment: 2^16 bytes, [apparently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). Also: "The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers."

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766854/1358777

Comment: Incredibly, the Mysql docs do not directly provide this info. The closest I've found is the "Storage Required" formula which only implies the answer, once you compute it: "L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16"

Answer (score 280):

A `BLOB` can be 65535 bytes (64 KB) maximum.

If you need more consider using:

- a `MEDIUMBLOB` for 16777215 bytes (16 MB)
- a `LONGBLOB` for 4294967295 bytes (4 GB).

See [Storage Requirements for String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#id899830) for more info.

Comment: In other words, `BLOB` ≈ 64KB, `MEDIUMBLOB` ≈ 16MB and `LONGBLOB` ≈ 4GB

Comment: I am using medium blob, but it accepts till 1MB data only. Why? Is there anywhere I have to set this size?

Comment: @SIBHIS it might be dependant on your input method. How are you inserting ?

Answer (score 20):

May or may not be accurate, but according to this site: http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php.

> BLOB  A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.

The MySQL manual says:

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT
>   object is determined by its type, but
>   the largest value you actually can
>   transmit between the client and server
>   is determined by the amount of
>   available memory and the size of the
>   communications buffers

I think the first site gets their answers from interpreting the MySQL manual, per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html