# Maximum length for MySQL type text

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a form for sending private messages and want to set the `maxlength` value of a textarea appropriate to the max length of a `text` field in my MySQL database table. How many characters can a type text field store?

If a lot, would I be able to specify length in the database text type field as I would with varchar?

Comment: Typing 64k into a simple text field? painful...

Comment: @Marc B Never underestimate a user's ability to paste vast amounts of garbage into a private text message field.

Comment: And that's why you should restrict the textfield capacity and always validate your inputs...

Comment: @jpangamarca on the Server Side of course

Comment: @Binozo Yeah, server side (Java/JavaEE/JakartaEE: preconditions, JSF validators, Bean Validation). Client side validation equals to nothing.

Answer (score 862, accepted):

See for maximum numbers:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

```
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT       L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8    (255 Bytes)
BLOB, TEXT               L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16   (64 Kilobytes)
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT   L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24   (16 Megabytes)
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT       L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32   (4 Gigabytes)
```

L is the number of bytes in your text field. So the maximum number of chars for text is 2<sup>16</sup>-1 (using single-byte characters). Means 65 535 chars(using single-byte characters).

**UTF-8/MultiByte encoding**: using MultiByte encoding each character might consume more than 1 byte of space. For UTF-8 space consumption is between 1 to 4 bytes per char.

Comment: @fyr- Here what is means for L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16 ? Could you please define it a bit more ? Other wise you can tell me how many chars we can store in text field ? Please....

Comment: @J.J. L is the number of chars and the number of chars need to be less than 2 to the power of 16. 2^16 = 65536. So you might enter 65535 chars which consume 65535 bytes + 3 bytes = 65 538 bytes per full filled field.

Comment: Edited to make the numbers a bit more clear. Also, note that AFAIK InnoDB stores the first 768 bytes of those BLOBs and TEXTs in the row itself so watch out for the limit a row can store inline.

Comment: Note that the size limits are in *bytes*.  So if you use multi-byte characters, you don't get 2^16 characters in a TEXT column, you get however many characters you can store in 2^16 bytes.

Comment: TINYBLOB is 2^8 which is equal 256 not 255. You can calculate it yourself :)

Comment: What Bill Karwin said. BYTES, NOT CHARACTERS. A character may use 4 bytes to store with the given encoding (like  in UTF-8).

Comment: Under UTF-8 encoding, most of the old ASCII range characters only take 1 byte, but as @basic6 said they can take up to 4 bytes in some cases.

Comment: Note that in MySQL, utf8 consumes up to 3 bytes, utf8mb4 consumes up to 4. [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Comment: Best explanation and contribution from all, kudos, helped me guiding to the right direction.

Answer (score 153):

| Type | Approx. Length | Exact Max. Length Allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TINYTEXT | 256 Bytes | 255 characters |
| TEXT | 64 Kilobytes | 65,535 characters |
| MEDIUMTEXT | 16 Megabytes | 16,777,215 characters |
| LONGTEXT | 4 Gigabytes | 4,294,967,295 characters |

Basically, it's like:

"Exact Max. Length Allowed" = "Approx. Length" in bytes - 1

**Note:** If using multibyte characters (like Arabic, where each Arabic character takes 2 bytes), the column "Exact Max. Length Allowed" for `TINYTEXT` can hold be up to 127 Arabic characters (Note: space, dash, underscore, and other such characters, are 1-byte characters).

Answer (score 143):

TINYTEXT: 256 bytes
TEXT: 65,535 bytes
MEDIUMTEXT: 16,777,215 bytes
LONGTEXT: 4,294,967,295 bytes

Comment: I think TINYTEXT should be 255 bytes instead of 256 bytes, according to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 27):

> ```
> TINYTEXT 256 bytes
> TEXT 65,535 bytes ~64kb
> MEDIUMTEXT 16,777,215 bytes ~16MB
> LONGTEXT 4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
> ```

`TINYTEXT` is a string data type that can store up to to `255` characters.

`TEXT` is a string data type that can store up to `65,535` characters. `TEXT` is commonly used for brief articles.

`LONGTEXT` is a string data type with a maximum length of `4,294,967,295` characters. Use `LONGTEXT` if you need to store large text, such as a chapter of a novel.

Comment: side note: I think 4.3 billion characters would be more of an entire book than just a chapter ^^
Assuming 80 characters per line and 50 lines per page (both of which are pretty generous and would probably be an a4-sized book), that still equals about 1 *millIion* pages. Would be a pretty fuckin' long chapter :D MEDIUMTEXT would equal about 4000 pages with the same numbers, which would still be a lot, but normal TEXT would be only about 16 pages, which might be too short.

Comment: They are in _bytes_, not _characters_.

Answer (score 21):

Acording to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html, the limit is `L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16`, or 64k.

You shouldn't need to concern yourself with limiting it, it's automatically broken down into chunks that get added as the string grows, so it won't always blindly use 64k.

Answer (score 9):

> How many characters can a type text field store?

According to [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-type-overview.html) You can use maximum of 21,844 characters if the charset is UTF8

> If a lot, would I be able to specify length in the db text type field as I would with varchar?

You dont need to specify the length. If you need more character use data types MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT. With VARCHAR, specifieng length is not for Storage requirement, it is only for how the data is retrieved from data base.

Answer (score 2):

`TEXT` is a string data type that can store up to 65,535 characters.
But still if you want to store more data then change its data type to `LONGTEXT`

ALTER TABLE `name_tabel` CHANGE `text_field` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_general_ci` NOT NULL;

Answer (score 1):

For the MySql version 8.0.

### Numeric Type Storage Requirements

```
Data Type       Storage Required
TINYINT         1 byte
SMALLINT        2 bytes
MEDIUMINT       3 bytes
INT, INTEGER    4 bytes
BIGINT          8 bytes
FLOAT(p)        4 bytes if 0 <= p <= 24, 8 bytes if 25 <= p <= 53
FLOAT           4 bytes
DOUBLE, REAL    8 bytes
DECIMAL(M,D), NUMERIC(M,D)  Varies; see following discussion
BIT(M)  approximately (M+7)/8 bytes
```

Values for DECIMAL (and NUMERIC) columns are represented using a binary format that packs nine decimal (base 10) digits into four bytes. Storage for the integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately. Each multiple of nine digits requires four bytes, and the “leftover” digits require some fraction of four bytes. The storage required for excess digits is given by the following table.

Date and Time Type Storage Requirements
For TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP columns, the storage required for tables created before MySQL 5.6.4 differs from tables created from 5.6.4 on. This is due to a change in 5.6.4 that permits these types to have a fractional part, which requires from 0 to 3 bytes.

```
Data Type   Storage Required Before MySQL 5.6.4   Storage Required as of MySQL 5.6.4
YEAR        1 byte                                1 byte
DATE        3 bytes                               3 bytes
TIME        3 bytes                               3 bytes + fractional seconds storage
DATETIME    8 bytes                               5 bytes + fractional seconds storage
TIMESTAMP   4 bytes                               4 bytes + fractional seconds storage
```

As of MySQL 5.6.4, storage for YEAR and DATE remains unchanged. However, TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP are represented differently. DATETIME is packed more efficiently, requiring 5 rather than 8 bytes for the nonfractional part, and all three parts have a fractional part that requires from 0 to 3 bytes, depending on the fractional seconds precision of stored values.

```
Fractional Seconds Precision    Storage Required
0                               0 bytes
1, 2                            1 byte
3, 4                            2 bytes
5, 6                            3 bytes
```

For example, TIME(0), TIME(2), TIME(4), and TIME(6) use 3, 4, 5, and 6 bytes, respectively. TIME and TIME(0) are equivalent and require the same storage.

For details about internal representation of temporal values, see MySQL Internals: Important Algorithms and Structures.

String Type Storage Requirements
In the following table, M represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.

```
Data Type                    Storage Required
CHAR(M)                      The compact family of InnoDB row formats optimize storage for variable-length character sets. See COMPACT Row Format Characteristics. Otherwise, M × w bytes, <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set.
BINARY(M)                    M bytes, 0 <= M <= 255
VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)     L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 − 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT           L + 1 bytes, where L < 28
BLOB, TEXT                   L + 2 bytes, where L < 216
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT       L + 3 bytes, where L < 224
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT           L + 4 bytes, where L < 232
ENUM('value1','value2',...)  1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)
SET('value1','value2',...)   1, 2, 3, 4, or 8 bytes, depending on the number of set members (64 members maximum)
```