# What is the Max limit of mysql text type

Tags: mysql

I am working on an app that allows people to upload data via pdf files. After reading the pdf with my app, i also like to store all characters in the pdf from the first page to the last page.

My fear is that a pdf file can be up to 80mb which can contain over 1 billion characters. 
Can mysql handle such large amount of characters?

Comment: This had been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text

Comment: Just because MySQL *can* store the data doesn't mean that it *should*.  Why don't you store your files in that highly optimised file storage database, your filesystem?  THen *relate* to relevant MySQL records (a *relational* database management system) with a suitable key into that file storage database (i.e. the file's path).

Comment: Eggyal has VERY valid point

Comment: This would have been an option but i want searching the pdf file to b a lot more faster so i dont have too open the pdf with my app every time.

Comment: @UchennaOkafor: If you're trying to search the binary content of PDF files (least of all huge ones) for character strings using MySQL's pattern matching operators, you're just begging to be subjected to a whole world of pain.  Good luck with that.

Comment: @eggyal I am not going to use mysql matching operators. i only want to convert the characters to utf8 and index them using apache solr or shipnex to reduce load on the server during bg operations.

Comment: @UchennaOkafor: You can index files which are stored outside of MySQL, e.g. using [Solr Cell](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) (which will even parse PDF files correctly for you in order to properly extract the searchable content).  Likewise Sphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL data storage requirements can be found here: [MySQL5 storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

There I find this table (L = length of string):

```
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT         L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8 = 256b
BLOB, TEXT                 L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16 = 65.536 = 65kb
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT     L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24 = 16.777.216 = 16mb
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT         L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32 = 4.294.967.296 = 4.3gb
```

So for 80Mb page, you need a LONGTEXT. For PDF I would advice a LONGBLOB type, since this is binary format.

For the record: Eggyal has a point that it is better NOT to store this PDF in the database, but on disk. So I would advice on no doing it via the database, if you really need to put it in MySQL use a **LONGBLOB**

Comment: Nice. Now i understand better how this is calculated

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

```
TINYTEXT    256 bytes    
TEXT        65,535 bytes        ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT  16,777,215 bytes    ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
```