# MySQL - Preferred data type for storing messages/conversations

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm adding a Messaging System on my site. So my question, just like on the title, what is the most preferred or the best data-type for storing messages/conversation in the database? I read some articles here about varchar and text. So which is the preferred one.

Also, can you share some techniques about making the Messaging System using php, mysql and ajax?

Comment: `TEXT` should be OK assuming you don't have extremely long messages.

Comment: Does it have any limit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text ... these limits are in bytes, you would calculate the number of characters depending on the _encoding_ you plan to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use VARCHAR to store the title, and TEXT to store the messages.
Varchar is faster when it's smaller, but Text is better to store long messages.
Use Varchar to store Variables (name, title ...) and Text to store long messages.

Comment: Let's say a simple reply, a short one. Text is preferred?

Comment: Yes, you should use Text.