# How to save data of unknown length in mysql or any database

Tags: java, mysql, database

i am making a chatting software in java in which the chats are to be stored in the database but how the  chats of different size can be stored in it.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text)

Comment: thx. for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use text file locally for saving chat histories and sync that text file in database in BLOB field. using stream writers you can easily retrieve through saved data.

Best luck,
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

there are many types that can store a large amount of data  like

> TINYTEXT 256 bytes
>
> TEXT 65,535 bytes ~64kb
>
> MEDIUMTEXT 16,777,215 bytes ~16MB
>
> LONGTEXT 4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB

or you can use BLOB to store data as file ,i hope this example will help
[Insert file data into MySQL database using JDBC example](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc)

Comment: but this will take lots of the space even if the size of the text is not so long

Comment: so is there any way where we can avoid it