# What is the DEFAULT maximum length of TextField Django?

Tags: mysql, django, database, textarea, textfield

I want to know what is the maximum length of TextField in Django models. I know they cannot limit maximum length but I want to know the real maximum length of the TextField type. Please help me solve this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**`models.TextField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)'s maximum size purely relies on the database you are using. If you are using **MYSQL**, it uses the **`longtext`** data type to store the content, which can hold up to **4 Gigabytes**

Ref: [Maximum length for MySQL type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

The Django DB Docs will tell you, that max_length=255 is guaranteed to work always (for `CharField()` not `TextField()`). If you need something of the amount you've specified in your question, I'd suggest to use a TextField. It depends on the backend database. If you use MySQL 5.6 then there is a limit of 65,535