# Default size of text data type MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

What is the default size of text in MySQL.

**create table Temp ( Name text, Age int);**

What will be the maximum number of characters I can enter in Name column?

Comment: You should refer to the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum length for MySQL type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text)

Comment: Refer to : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: the storage is defined in terms of bytes, not characters. while each latin characters only use 1-byte, other characters can consume 1 to 4 bytes.

Comment: *What is the default size of text in MySQL.* Default size of TEXT datatype column is equal to the size of the default value for this column. If default value is not defined then NULL is assigned, which' size is NULL (but the column nullability occupies 1 byte per row).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL provides four TEXT types: TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, and LONGTEXT.

```
     TINYTEXT – 255 Bytes 
     TEXT – 64KB 
     MEDIUMTEXT – 16MB
     LONGTEXT – 4GB
```

Comment: What is the default size if I don't specify any size. Ex. for char it is 1 like that.

Comment: the size is not expressed in char but in bytes because  with unicode  a char can consume 1 or 2 or 4 byte ..  dependo on your character set and collation ..  if you use TEXT you can use fro 1 to 65KB alias 65536 byte  . this is basic in computer science ...