# A strange problem with MariaDB text，losing data

Tags: jdbc, text, mariadb, innodb

In some cases, MariaDB will lose the data of the text field.
My table is

```sql
create table tt(
     id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
   info text 
)
```

My SQL is

```sql
update tt join 
    (select 'StringValue' as info , 1 as id ) a using(id)
    set tt.info = a.info
```

The StringValue is a string data that more than 65535 bytes;

I can execute this SQL successfully using Java JDBC, but only a few bytes can be written.

For example, StringValue is a String data with 65538 bytes, after executing the SQL, tt.info has only 2 bytes.

My MariaDB version is 10.4.7, innodb_page_size is 16kb.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As an aside, you are not using MySQL, you're using MariaDB. Although MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL, it is not the same database system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum length for MySQL type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text)

Comment: @P.Salmon - That link does not seem to explain how the first 64KB can be tossed, keeping the next 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be simply this:

```
UPDATE tt
    SET info = 'StringValue'
    WHERE id = 1;
```

But, if the string is bigger than `TEXT` can hold, it will either give a warning or an error, depending on some setting.  Is that what you are asking about?  Does the code check for warnings and errors?

If you change the column definition from `TEXT` to `MEDIUMTEXT`, the limit is 16MB instead of 64KB.  (Both of those numbers are in *bytes*, not *characters*.

You say it has 2 bytes -- do they happen to be the last 2 bytes?

Comment: Yes , that is same with UPDATE tt SET info = 'StringValue'  WHERE id = 1 ;But my sql is dynamic created , i can not change the sql . And what strange is there is errors or warinings do they happen to be the last 2 bytes  -- no, they happen to be the first 2 bytes.