# How should I organize user data with several rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently developing a quiz-app, that keeps track of user data, such as :

- the sets they've studied by the ID of the specific set ([1,2,6,12])
- the friends they have by the id of the user ([1,2,3,4])
- their schedule(
  {"2022-07-03 00:00:00":{"551":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"552":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"553":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"554":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"555":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"556":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"1"},"557":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"6"},"558":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"6"},"559":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"6"},"560":{"type":"Flashcards","setid":"6"}}})
- every individual day they've logged in (["05/15/2022","05/17/2022","05/18/2022","05/19/2022","05/22/2022","05/23/2022","05/24/2022","05/25/2022","05/28/2022","05/29/2022","05/30/2022","05/31/2022","06/02/2022","06/05/2022","06/07/2022","06/08/2022","06/10/2022","06/11/2022","06/13/2022","06/14/2022","06/15/2022","06/17/2022","06/18/2022","06/19/2022","06/20/2022","06/22/2022","06/24/2022","06/25/2022","06/26/2022","06/28/2022","06/29/2022","06/30/2022","07/01/2022","07/02/2022"])
- Note: there is quite a lot of other types of information that is stored inside the table.

**All of this aforementioned information is collected in a mysql table called "users", which has rows for each user, with accompanying data (as mentioned above).**

It has recently come to my attention that MySQL has data limits for the amount of data that can be represented in a given row (around 65K bytes). If I continue to represent data this way, I believe that at scale (assume a user uses the app for 5 years, imagine the amount of data inside the "every individual day they've logged in" table), I will face MySQL's data limits and it may cause problems in the future.

Here's a picture, showing how the information is represented inside of the table "users"
[image: Here's a picture, showing how the information is represented inside of the table "users"]

[image]

How would I better represent this type of table? Should I use multiple tables inside an SQL database? How should I format it? Do I not have to worry about the data limit, and should I continue saving data in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are packing way too much information in each row. The *structure* of your data is not being represented in a way that allows MySQL to do what it is good at. You are just creating big buckets for each user and stashing them in MySQL.

To make this work better, you can either create tables to store each relationship (this is, after all, a *relational* database) like `user_login`, `user_friend_requests`, and so on. The direct answer to your question is that each cell in your table should be a table itself.

OR, you can embrace the blob, and use something like mongodb, which is much more suited for storing and retrieving the data in a way that fits your mindset. Since you don't do any real queries on the data, a NoSQL solution would probably fit you better.

So the "right" answer to your question is "modify your schema to store this data better, or switch your database to match the way you want to store the data."

However, having said all that, since it seems you are storing JSON in those cells, you can use the JSON data type (max size 1GB but better if you don't use so much - see https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/how-large-can-json-documents-be), or LONGTEXT, 4GB. (Assuming you are running in a 64-bit environment - see [Maximum length for MySQL type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766781/maximum-length-for-mysql-type-text)).

The JSON data type actually has some pretty cool features.