# How to upload a base64 encoded image and save to mysql database?

Tags: feathersjs, mysql2

Currently, I am encoding images in a `Vue.js` application to base64 and save them in a `MySQL` database using `feathers.js` and `feathers-objection`. The data type in the table is `LONGTEXT`, which works fine for small images.

Sometimes, if the image is larger (>1MB) I get a `Data too long for column` error from the database driver `mysql2`.

In the `feathers` documentation they are saving images to a blob storage, like google drive, which unfortunately is no option for this use case.

The table definition is done via `knex.js`:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable("attachments", (table) => {
      table.increments("id");
      table.integer("ticketId");
      table.text("uri", "LONGTEXT");
      table.integer("size");
      table.string("type");
      table.string("name");
      table.timestamp("createdAt").nullable();
      table.timestamp("updatedAt").nullable();
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Created attachments table")) // eslint-disable-line no-console
    .catch((e) => console.error("Error creating attachments table", e)); // eslint-disable-line no-console
};
```

Are there some other options, e.g. datatypes to save longer base64 encoded URIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at the code of knex.js and found this:

```js
  text(column) {
    switch (column) {
      case 'medium':
      case 'mediumtext':
        return 'mediumtext';
      case 'long':
      case 'longtext':
        return 'longtext';
      default:
        return 'text';
    }
  }
```

In other words, the text input is **NOT** case insensitive, so the following should create a column with a `LONGTEXT` type:

```js
table.text("uri", "longtext"); // or just "long"
```

What happened is that the text type in your instruction defaulted to normal `TEXT` although you thought it was `LONGTEXT`. So when you've tried to store an image that was longer than 64 Kilobytes, you've got an error.

To know which type you want to use here is a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866693/10408987):

| Type | Approx. Length | Exact Max. Length Allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TINYTEXT | 256 Bytes | 255 characters |
| TEXT | 64 Kilobytes | 65,535 characters |
| MEDIUMTEXT | 16 Megabytes | 16,777,215 characters |
| LONGTEXT | 4 Gigabytes | 4,294,967,295 characters |

P.S. Storing images in databases is still not the best option and has a [few downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay). So you may want to have the possibility to switch later.