# Codeigniter session size limit

Tags: php, mysql, session, codeigniter, cookies

When storing the session in the database via

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
```

Is the size of the data limited to the size of the user_data field which is TEXT ... ? Not 4kb like a normal cookie.

Comment: I don't know for sure. But if it is, it would be very dumb.

Comment: If you save to a database, the data is indeed limited by the size of the field your saving the data it. So if you use `TEXT`, you should have plenty of storage available.

Comment: If you look at line #293 of session.php it still sets the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further clarify my comment above, when you elect to save the session data in a database, CodeIgniter doesn't set a cookie (other than the session id of course) but saves all of the information that it would have set in a cookie in your database.

If you have a look at the `sess_write` in the `Session` class located in `./system/libraries/`, if you have enabled the use of a database, you'll see that it serializes the data using `serialize` and saves it directly to the database. **There is no restriction on length imposed by CodeIgniter when saving to a database.**

For your convenience, here's a link to the source code: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/fe2247a927ab/system/libraries/Session.php#cl-252.

**The only restriction is set by the field you chose to use to save the data in your database.** For more information on the data type storage requirements of MySQL, read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: So a session around 50kb wouldn't cause CI to have issues? I've been having issues where my session data was outputting in the profiler but wasn't available in the controller. I switched out to this session library http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Session_Hybrid/ and the problem is resolved.

Comment: @ringerce - It shouldn't be a problem. The session itself is essentially just another array that gets serialized and unserialized when read or saved (unless you use cookies). I store [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) objects in my session which tend to be quite large without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same "size limit" issue even i have `ci_session` table for storing

I just change in data type of `user_data = longtext` and my problem solve

although session size is limited to size of longtext NOT UNLIMITED

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer your question. from the class code:

```
// Are we saving custom data to the DB?  If not, all we do is update the cookie
if ($this->sess_use_database === FALSE)
{
    $this->_set_cookie();
    return;
}
```

even the comments are from the class itself. so it updates the cookie IF not using the database.

Answer (score 0):

The [CI session docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) specify a **BLOB** data column for your session data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

According to the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) this storage type requires *L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16*. This means the BLOB (and therefore the serialized data in your session table) is [limited to 65,535 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775571/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-data-i-can-put-in-a-blob-column-in-mysql). NOTE that this limit applies to the length of your session data *once it has been serialized* which may cause some inflation relative to the amount of storage used in RAM.

You might, of course, choose a different data type when defining your session table. E.g., **MEDIUMBLOB** instead of blob would give you 16MB. This may or may not introduce performance issues.