# When using BLOB in MySQL, is it possible to put a maximum size on allowable image files?

Tags: mysql, image, blob

I want to make the maximum allowable size of image files 25MB within a table. However I haven't found a way to make this happen. Right now I'm using MEDIUMBLOB since its maximum is 16MB but I want it just a tiny bit larger. So is it possible?

I'm pretty new to MySQL so I apologize if what I'm trying to ask seems unclear.

Comment: This question has been asked a gazillian times here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of data I can put in a BLOB column in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775571/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-data-i-can-put-in-a-blob-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @steveluscher he's asking for the ability to set a user limit, not for the default system one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended not to store images in the database.
I would suggest to follow below process to store images
If you want to store profile picture of every user while creating a user account
 - create a extra field user table in the database to store profile picture name.
 - First insert other detail in the database and get the last inserted id (ie primary key of a user table).
 - Upload image in one of the folder on the server and rename that image with unique key (for example : "profile_pic_" and concat with primary key of the user table)
 - Update the image name in the user table in the databse.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a table whose rows represent possible ‘exceptions’

```
CREATE TABLE exceptions (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    message VARCHAR(255),
    UNIQUE KEY (id, message)
);
INSERT INTO exceptions (1, 'Images must be <=25MB');
```

## Define a trigger on your images table

Assuming the BLOB column is called ‘data’:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER assert_image_size BEFORE INSERT ON images
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(NEW.data) > 25000000 THEN
      INSERT INTO exceptions (1, 'Images must be <=25MB');
    END IF;
  END;
//
delimiter ;
```

MySQL will throw a duplicate key error, and the error message will contain the text “Image too large”.

Comment: But seriously, validate this at the application level. Hacks on hacks.