# Download Full size of File in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, blob

I have a problem downloading the **Blob file** from MYSQL using php.

Here is my **php script** in downloading file:

```
        $querysel = "Select * from file where file_id = '$fileid'";
        $resultsel = mysql_query($querysel);
        $rowsel = mysql_fetch_array($resultsel);

        $filename = $rowsel['file_name'];
        $mimetype = $rowsel['mime_type'];
        $filesize = $rowsel['file_size'];

        header("Content-length: ".$filesize);
        header("Content-type: ".$mimetype);
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
        header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
        echo $filename;
```

And this table in **mysql**:[image]

**PROBLEM**   [UPDATED]

1. What seems to be the problem here is that after downloading the file, the file size from that particular file don't match with the file size saved in mysql. I don't know why?
2. I also encounter this small problem, After I downloaded the Powerpoint and delete it and download it again would be automatically saved to downloads and will automatically be opened. Is that normal?

Example:

The BLOB file with 6.8MB of file size was supposed to be downloaded with 6.8MB also but what happened here is that the file size of the downloaded file is only **25bytes**. Why?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try this? http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/07/file-download-coding-using-php-and-mysql.html

Comment: use unserialize on file_content column : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php
And after check file size

Comment: I think you'll find "01 LCD Slides 1.pps" is about 25 chars. Maybe you wanted to return the file, not the filename?

Comment: You are doing `echo $filename;`.  All you are doing is making a text file with the string "01 LCD Slides 1.pps".

Comment: last line: `echo $filename` do not send content but only a filename (probably 25bytes long?)

Comment: P.S. It's usually suggested that you upload files to the filesystem, *not* the database.  You can store the filename, path, and metadata in the db, but it's usually not suggested to store the file in the db.

Comment: one more reason not to put files into a db

Comment: `BLOB` isn't large enough to store such a big file. 6.8 MiB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: Where is the code that is writing the content of the file to the response? You posted the code that is writing the header only. If that's your entire code, then that's the problem. After the header, you need to write the content of the file as a byte array to the response.

Comment: I updated the question. Please see it. Really need help. and also thanks for the comments.

Comment: Injection vulnerability: check. Use of _deprecated_ extension: check. Please stop using `mysql`, it's deprecated. Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` instead, and learn to use prepared statements

Comment: Quoted from an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775571/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-data-i-can-put-in-a-blob-column-in-mysql *"A BLOB can be 65535 bytes maximum. If you need more consider using a MEDIUMBLOB for 16777215 bytes or a LONGBLOB for 4294967295 bytes. See Storage Requirements for String Types for more info."*

Comment: Did you not see what I said [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567649/download-full-size-of-file-in-php-mysql#comment52990508_32567649)? I didn't write *"BLOB **is probably not** large enough to store such a big file."* - I wrote *"BLOB **isn't** large enough to store such a big file."* "Isn't" as in **"is NOT".**

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got no problem storing blob and actually I used **MEDIUMBLOB** to store upto 16MB of file and what I actually did in my code was to trap that if the file is larger than **10MB** then I wouldn't be store in the db. **MEDIUMBLOB** not **BLOB**. If you could just see on my db table I am able to store the file.

Comment: fair enough. well.. see Riggs' answer below. @Makudex

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah that's what I actually did. *Size checking* is the word :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you want to be echoing the file contents and not its filename

```
    $querysel = "Select * from file where file_id = '$fileid'";
    $resultsel = mysql_query($querysel);
    $rowsel = mysql_fetch_array($resultsel);

    $filename = $rowsel['file_name'];
    $mimetype = $rowsel['mime_type'];
    $filesize = $rowsel['file_size'];

    header("Content-length: ".$filesize);
    header("Content-type: ".$mimetype);
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
    header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");

    echo $rowsel['file_content'];          //<-- changed line
```

Of course you still probably have a problem with the larger files in that a BLOB is not large enough to hold 6.8 Meg. See @Fred-ii- comment for details and links to all the relevant info you need to check that.

Even a LONGBLOB is only 4,294,967,295 bytes, thats a little over 4Gig, so you probably need to do some size checking before storing to even a LONGBLOB.

The safest suggestion would be to store the actual files on disk and only the filename and path in the database.