# Laravel string to file limit

Tags: php, mysql, file, laravel, ftp

I have one database table where images are stored as strings. I'm trying to get this field content and add it to ftp server as image.

```
$data = $tbExpenseFile->full_image;
$hash = Str::random(16);
\File::makeDirectory(storage_path().'/storage/'.$hash);
$tbFile = storage_path().'/storage/'.$hash.'/'.$tbExpenseFile->full_image_name;
\File::put($tbFile, $data);
```

It's working, but bigger images are not uploaded fully, 1/4 from image is visible and remaining part is gray. In ftp these image sizes are 1048576 == 1mb.

I'm trying to figure out what can be the limit, maybe database string read limit, because laravel put method uses file_put_contents, so i think the problem is not there.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775571/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-data-i-can-put-in-a-blob-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem, need to deal with PDO settings in database config:

```
'options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216)
```