# PHP image upload to mysql issue - only showing part of the image

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, xampp

I'm pretty sure my code is correct. The issue I have is that, when viewing the image, there is only some of the image that is showing. I think it has something to do with my database that i'm uploading to, but I can't figure out what

Here is my code:

form for the upload

```
    <form id="form2" method="post" name="postForm" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>Post News here</h2>
<p>Title:</p>
<input type="text" required placeholder="Enter a title" maxlength="30" name="postTitle">
<p>Body:</p>
<input type="textarea" required placeholder="Enter a body" maxlength="250" name="postBody">
<p>Link/ Reference:</p>
<input type="text" required placeholder="Enter a link or reference" maxlength="100" name="postLinkRef">
<p>Image to upload:</p>
<input type="file" name="imageTest">
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

inserting the image

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "password";
$db = "userdata";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$userName,$password, $db);


if($connect)
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['imageTest']))
        {
        $postTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['postTitle']);
        $postBody = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['postBody']);
        $postLink = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['postLinkRef']);
        //address, postcode
        //admin priveleges for scertain accounts
        //wont allow me to use $_FILES and i dont know why...
        $postImageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_FILES['imageTest']['name']); 
        $postImageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, file_get_contents($_FILES["imageTest"]["tmp_name"]));
        $postImageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_FILES["imageTest"]["type"]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO news(title, body, link, imageName, imageData) VALUES('$postTitle','$postBody','$postLink','$postImageName','$postImageData')";
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
        {
            echo "Your post has been uploaded\n\n";
            echo "Thank you for your post $testUserName\n\n";
            echo "<a href='index.php'>Got to your news </a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry, something went wrong!! Check to make sure the image your are uploading is a jpeg image (not any other file)!";
        }
        }
        mysqli_close($connect);
}
else
{
    echo "Fail connection";
}
?>
```

Showing the image

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "password";
$db = "userdata";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$userName,$password, $db);

    if(isset($_GET['postID']))
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['postID']);
        $q = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE postID = $id";
        $r = mysqli_query($connect, $q);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($r)==1)//id found in the table
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
            $imageData = $row["imageData"];
        }
        header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
        echo $imageData;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdqye.png)[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkte4.png)[image]

Comment: You're inserting raw binary content to the database (via `$postImagedata`). Is that a binary column?

Comment: the column is a blob type in my database? If i try and edit the attributes for that type and click binary it says i have an error with my syntax "binary not null" is this because the lines above may not necessarily have an image?

Comment: instead of saving binary content to database why don't you simply store image physically and save its path to the database, doing this your queries will work faster...

Comment: A BLOB (Binary Large OBject) column should be fine for this. Can you add more detail to your question about the actual problem you are seeing? Screenshots would be very helpful.

Comment: I've included the screenshots now

Comment: Those images look quite large. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5775601/3775731) the limit of a `BLOB` column is about 64KiB. You probably need to change the type to a `LONGBLOB` as per that answer.

Comment: That worked thanks a lot for the answer, I didn't realise there was a longblob available