# How do I use varbinary if I don't know the length of my text

Tags: mysql, encryption, text, aes, varbinary

I want to encrypt text using AES in mysql, but I have a small problem, because you need to use varbinary to store these.

Some of my datatypes are varchar and yes I can probably work out the length of my varbinary for these. However for my address fields I use the TEXT datatype, as we have Chinese addresses stored and these can be very long. I use the TEXT datatype because you do not need to specify a length in mysql.

The problem is that with varbinary you need to specify a length, and I don't really know the length because the addresses can be of any length.

Is there some kind of binary datatype I can use for AES where I don't have to specify the length of the data?

Comment: You're after `blob` or binary long object. If `varbinary` is charset-less equivalent to `varchar`, then that's what `blob` is to `text`.

Comment: Thank you. If you leave your comment as an answer I can vote you up

Comment: @Mjh That's Binary *Large* Object if I'm not mistaken. There is also a [`MEDIUMBLOB` and `LARGEBLOB`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5775601/589259) so calling it a Binary *Long* Object may confuse readers. Otherwise the hint is of course OK.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - thanks for the correction, added to the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per comments - you require `BLOB` data type, which is short for *Binary Large Object* (thanks Maarten Bodewes for clarification).

A `BLOB` data type won't store character set with the information and is equivalent to `TEXT` type, without a charset. As mentioned in the comments, there are other types such as `MEDIUMBLOB`, `TINYBLOB`, `LARGEBLOB`, they are all covered on [MySQL's manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).