# Can blob being altered when transiting between MySQL and SQLite?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, entity-framework-6

Brace yourselves for an inception of database (please, don't ask why we are doing this ^^):

Our application has 2 SQLite databases (let's call them `Cache` and `LocalRepository`). These two databases are encrypted (here is the connection string; `Data Source=%PATH_TO_FILE%;Password=%PWD%`). For some reasons, we store the `Cache` database into the `LocalRepository`. And for some other reasons, we are synchronizing the `LocalRepository` with a MySQL database (lets call it `GlobalRepository`).

As long as the application is extracting the `Cache` database from the `LocalRepository`, I can recreate the file and connect to it with success. But if the application updates the `LocalRepository` with the data from the `GlobalRepository`, I get the following error:

`database disk image is malformed`

The three databases are mapped through Entity Framework 6 and here is how everything is defined:

LocalRepository definition (SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE `LocalRepository` (
  [..]
  , `CacheData` BLOB NOT NULL
  [..]
);

public partial class LocalRepository
{
    [..]
    public byte[] CacheData { get; set; }
    [..]
}
```

GlobalRepository definition (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `schema`.`GlobalRepository` (
  [..]
  `CacheData` BLOB NOT NULL,
  [..]
);

public partial class GlobalRepository
{
    [..]
    public byte[] CacheData { get; set; }
    [..]
}
```

Saving to LocalRepository:

```
var cacheBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(cacheDatabaseFilePath);
var localRep = new LocalRepository
{
    [..]
    CacheData = cacheBytes,
    [..]
};
localRepositoryContext.Add(localRep);
localRepositoryContext.SaveChanges();
```

Pushing to GlobalRepository:

```
var localRep.Status = Status.Pushed;
var globalRep = new GlobalRepository
{
    [..]
    CacheData = localRep.CacheData,
    Status = localRep.Status,
    [..]
};
globalRepositoryContext.Add(localRep);

var saving = new Task[]
{
    globalRepositoryContext.SaveChangesAsync(),
    localRepositoryContext.SaveChangesAsync()
};

await Task.WhenAll(saving);
```

Updating from GlobalRepository:

```
var globalRep = globalRepositoryContext.Find(id);
var localRep = new LocalRepository
{
    [..]
    CacheData = globalRep.CacheData,
    [..]
};
localRepositoryContext.Add(localRep);
localRepositoryContext.SaveChanges();
```

Recreating the Cache:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(cacheFilePath, localRep.CacheData);
```

To summarize: The last operation copies to the disk altered bytes only when the CacheData comes from the `GlobalRepository`. And indeed, the recreated `Cache` is very small comparing to the original file (64 KB vs 1,7MB).

Where the bytes could be altered? As it is systematic, I guess the issue is related to the way MySQL stores byte comparing to SQLite.

Comment: Did you check if `globalRep.CacheData` is complete in the last code snippet?

Comment: I'd guess that some object is not a byte array and so does not write the actual blob contents. But I cannot see all the types involved here.

Comment: Just notice I forgot to add the push to GlobalRepository. Also add the EF6 generated entities.

Comment: @GertArnold: You are correct, the globalRep.CacheData is incomplete during the `Updating from GlobalRepository` phase. I just check and there is a limite for the blob type in MySQL ... 64KB (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5775601/2183236) ... I did not know about that ...