# High-quality image output becomes trimmed in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

For some reason, my 800x800px image becomes trimmed. But when I use my 80x80px it doesn't appear to be trimmed. How do I fix this? It also says that I have a blob - 64kib in my sql. How can I increase the limit?  Only 20% of the image is shown.
**Update: It is solved, I used mediumblob instead of blob.**

```
if(isset($_POST["insert"]))
{
     $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
     $query = "UPDATE users SET image='$file' WHERE email= '$param_email'";
     if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
     {
echo '<script>alert("Image Inserted into Database")</script>';
     }
}
?>
Html:
               <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" src=
                    <?php
                            $query = "SELECT image FROM users where email='$param_email'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {echo'"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'"';}?> name="image" id="image" />
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-info" />
               </form>

               <table>
               <?php
               $query = "SELECT image FROM users where email='$param_email'";
               $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
               {
                    echo '
                         <tr>
                              <td>
                                   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />
                              </td>
                         </tr>
                    ';
               }
               ?>
               </table>
JS:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#insert').click(function(){
          var image_name = $('#image').val();
          if(image_name == '')
          {
               alert("Please Select Image");
               return false;
          }
          else
          {
               var extension = $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
               if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
               {
                    alert('Invalid Image File');
                    $('#image').val('');
                    return false;
               }
          }
     });
});
</script>
```

Thanks guys! Please share this as well so that this can be solved faster :)

Comment: What do you mean by "trimmed"? Is it only 200x200px?

Comment: What should `<input type="file" src=` do?

Comment: view the image directly without css or html around it , and check the size there

Comment: Don't go live with this code, this code is prone to SQL injection vector attacks.

Comment: Can you describe all fields of your table (type, size)?

Comment: kerbholz it only shows like 20% of the image then the rest will not be seen like the bottom part is pure white.

Comment: Raymond Nijland What can I do to make it less prone to SQL injection. I don't know hot use PDO for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of data I can put in a BLOB column in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775571/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-data-i-can-put-in-a-blob-column-in-mysql)

Comment: TLDR: use `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`

Comment: Chris Lear, Thanks it worked!