# Database for storing mp3 in phpmyadmin

Tags: android, audio, phpmyadmin, blob, mp3

I'm doing a database for storing mp3 in phpmyadmin. I tried to use longblob, but my files are too long and I can not cast them into the database (audio file = 15MB). 
what is the other solution to keeping mp3 files in the database? I want to do it manually in phpmyadmin, because the application will use it to read. The database will be used not only by me, I am doing a project with friends so they also need to have access to the data.

Comment: Care to give more details on what kind of database you are using? Though i’d generally advice against it since retrieval and serialization would be too long for your database

Comment: Do you want/need absolutely to store the mp3 itself in the database? Not only the reference and store the file on disk/cdn?

Comment: @olibiaz would like only the reference and store the file on disk/cdn, because longblob does not work for me. 
I do not know how to do a reference in phpmyadmin to an mp3 file

Comment: Can you recommend which disk or cdn to store mp3 files on?

Comment: here is a cool idea.. get some webhost where you can host your data.. write a code to upload a file from android to your host and get the link reference of your file and store it in database..

Comment: _longblob_ is not [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775601/5156280) to 15mb with MySQL, so maybe there is another problem here.