# Truncated image displayed when tried to retrieve from mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to insert and retrieve image as BLOB data from my sql database.

I am able to insert it as BLOB. However, when I try to retrieve it,the retrieved image is truncated.

First it showed `OSError: image file is truncated`. By referring some posts I included the code  `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True`. Now there is no error.

But the image is still truncated.

This is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import filedialog
import mysql.connector
import io
from PIL import ImageFile

root = Tk()

browse_button = Button(root,text ='Browse',command = lambda:open_file())
browse_button.pack()

display_button = Button(root,text ='display',command =lambda:display_file())
display_button.pack()

def display_file():
    ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
    person = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="image")
    cursor_variable = person.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT data FROM image_db WHERE id = 5"
    cursor_variable.execute(sql)
    all_data = cursor_variable.fetchall()
    image = all_data[0][0]
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
    image.show()
    person.commit()
    person.close()


def open_file():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/write/PycharmProjects/slider/img", title='Select a File',
                                               filetypes=(('png files', '*.png'), ('jpeg files', '*.jpeg'),
                                                          ('jpg files', '*.jpg')))
    my_label = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    path = root.filename
    id = '5'


    person = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="image")
    cursor_variable = person.cursor()
    thedata = open(root.filename, 'rb').read()
    sql = "INSERT INTO image_db (id,data) VALUES ('" + id + "',%s)"
    cursor_variable.execute(sql, (thedata,))
    person.commit()
    person.close()


root.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make a guess at your problem, based on a few assumptions which aren't specified (or at least aren't specified clearly) in your question:

1. the `data` column of your `image_db` table has type `BLOB`, and not `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`.
2. The images you are attempting to upload are larger than 64KB.
3. You are not running your database in strict SQL mode.

The [MySQL docs on the `BLOB` and `TEXT` types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) state that:

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a BLOB or TEXT column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is truncated to fit and a warning is generated.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775601), the maximum length of a `BLOB` column is 64KB.  Combining all the assumptions together therefore gives us one possible explanation for the behaviour you are seeing.

I ran your code with some smallish images and it worked fine: the images displayed without truncation.

I would suggest changing the `data` column of your `image_db` table to `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`, depending on what size of images you need to store in your database.